# Using T-SQL, how do I generate a result that shows a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server, how do I generate a result set that shows a range of dates, like so:

```
StartDate    EndDate
01/01/2014   01/04/2014
01/08/2014   01/11/2014
01/14/2014   01/15/2014
```

The original data had the dates in this format:

```
ColumnA      DateColumn
blah         01/01/2014
blah         01/02/2014
blah         01/03/2014
blah         01/04/2014
blah         01/08/2014
blah         01/09/2014
blah         01/10/2014
blah         01/11/2014
blah         01/14/2014
blah         01/15/2014
```

Currently, I have a bunch of queries that does this, but I'm wondering if I can do something in less code:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateColumn) AS rownum,
       DateColumn
INTO #main
FROM MyTable

SELECT m1.DateColumn AS TBegin, 
       m2.DateColumn AS TEnd, 
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day, m2.TimePk, m1.TimePk), 0) AS Gap
INTO #Gap
FROM #main m1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #main m2
 ON m1.rownum = m2.rownum + 1
ORDER BY m1.DateColumn

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i_id, TBegin) AS rownum,
       TBegin
INTO #Begin
FROM #Gap
WHERE Gap <> 1
ORDER BY TBegin

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i_id, TEnd) AS rownum,
       TEnd
INTO #End
FROM (
     SELECT TEnd
     FROM #Gap
     WHERE Gap > 1
     UNION
     SELECT MAX(TBegin)
     FROM #Gap
     ) as t
ORDER BY TEnd

SELECT b.TBegin,
       e.TEnd
FROM #Begin b
INNER JOIN #End e
      ON b.i_id = e.i_id
      AND b.rownum = e.rownum
ORDER BY b.TBegin
```

Any ideas on how to simplify or approach this in an entirely different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to these is to identify the first date that has no date preceding it.  This is the beginning of a group.  Then I take the cumulative sum of that as a group identifier, and do the aggregation.

SQL Server 2008 doesn't have `lag` or cumulative sums, so I use correlated subqueries for this:

```
with mt as (
      select t.*,
             (case when (select top 1 t2.dateColumn
                         from MyTable t2
                         where t2.ColumnA = t.ColumnA and
                               t2.dateColumn < t.dateColumn
                         order by t2.dateColumn desc
                        ) = dateadd(day, -1, t.datecolumn)
                   then 0
                   else 1
              end) as IsStart
      from MyTable t
     ),
     mtcum as (
      select mt.*,
             (select sum(mt2.IsStart)
              from mt mt2
              where mt2.ColumnA = mt.ColumnA and
                    mt2.dateColumn <= mt.DateColumn
             ) as grpId
      from mt
     )
select ColumnA, min(dateColumn) as StartDate, max(dateColumn) as EndDate
from mtcum
group by ColumnA, grpId;
```

EDIT:

An easier way of approach this is with the observation that the difference between a sequence of dates and a sequence of numbers is constant.

```
select columnA, min(dateColumn) as StartDate, max(dateColumn) as EndDate
from (select mt.*, row_number() over (partition by ColumnA order by datecolumn) as seqnum
      from mytable mt
     ) t
group by columnA, dateadd(day, - seqnum, datecolumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. It's still fairly complex though. It uses inner queries to find the first date that is after a gap for each date. This way all days belonging to the same group of dates can be grouped together.

```
select MIN(DateColumn) StartDate, MAX(DateColumn) EndDate from
    (select X.DateColumn, MIN(Y.DateColumn) MinOverGap from 
        (select DateColumn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) RowNumber
        from MyTable) X
    left join 
        (select DateColumn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) RowNumber
        from MyTable) Y
        on DATEADD(d, Y.RowNumber - 1, X.DateColumn) <> DATEADD(d, X.RowNumber -1, Y.DateColumn) AND X.DateColumn < Y.DateColumn
    group by x.DateColumn) grouped
group by MinOverGap
order by 1
```